# Prove that a system of linear equations, will have infinitely many solutions whenever there is a specific value.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

I have a question where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are elements of $\Bbb R$, and I have to show that a system of linear equations will have infinitely many solutions whenever $\beta$ is an element of $\bigl[ -\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2\bigr]$.

There are three variables that have values like $\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha, \beta x$, etc. Now I know how to solve regular multi-variable linear equations to check if a linear system has infinite solutions or not, but this one is really tricky.... I don't even know where to start.

PS. I am really bad at math,  I don't even know how to read notations.

Here's the actual question:

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$  $\in$ R; then show that the following system of linear equations, will have infinite many solutions whenever $\beta$  $\in$ [- $\sqrt 2$, $\sqrt 2$ ];

$\
 - x + (\sin \alpha )y - (\cos \alpha )z = 0\\
\beta x + (\sin \alpha )y + (cos\alpha )z = 0\\
 x + (cos\alpha )y + (sin\alpha )z = 0
$

Comment: How about including this system of linear equations in your question?

Comment: Sure let me do that.

Comment: I just added the equation to the question.

Comment: Think of it as $Ax=0$, with $x=(x,y,z)^T$ a vector, and $A$ a 3-by-3 matrix. For $Ax=0$ to have more than one solution, $A$ must be singular, therefore $\det(A)=0$. Solve this to get the conditions on $\beta$

Comment: @user36196 You should write this up as an answer.

Comment: If the trig functions are confusing you, replace them temporarily with simple variables.

Comment: Still no clue. The type that I know is you would have 3 equations with three variables and you would eliminate one variable by multiplying equations with some number and then add or subtract that equation with another and so on to get values for all three variables and based on the value you would say if it has solution or not.

Comment: I think you've written the linear system incorrectly. Can you check the coefficients?

Comment: I should point out that whether or not this system has an infinite number of solutions also depends on the value of $\alpha$. The condition that you have for $\beta$ is necessary—if it’s outside of this range, then there can’t be an infinite number of solutions—but it’s not sufficient. E.g., with $\beta=0$, you must also have $\cos2\alpha+\sin2\alpha=0$.

Comment: I double checked and I made no mistake writing it.

Comment: Exactly I was thinking of the same thing but then I thought I didn't know how to solve it so I posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

Taking user36196’s suggestion, compute the determinant of $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&\sin\alpha&-\cos\alpha \\ \beta & \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha \\ 1&\cos\alpha&\sin\alpha \end{bmatrix}.$$ For there to be an infinite number of solutions to the system, this determinant must vanish. After a bit of simplification, this condition results in the equation $$\beta = \cos2\alpha+\sin2\alpha.$$ Now, the right-hand side can be rewritten as $\sqrt2 \sin\left(2\alpha+\frac\pi4\right),$ so clearly $\beta\in\left[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2\right]$ for this to hold, but that condition by itself is not sufficent for there to be an infinite number of solutions to the system.