# How to show infinite solutions of linear equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

For example we have α, β belongs to $\Bbb R$, then how to show that the following system of linear equations will have infinite many solutions whenever β belongs to $[−\sqrt 2,\sqrt2]$?
   $$\left\{ \begin{align}
-x + \sin \alpha\,y - \cos\alpha\,z=0,\\
    \beta\, x + \sin \alpha\,y + \cos\alpha\,z = 0,\\
    x + \cos\alpha\,y + \sin \alpha\,)z= 0.
\end{align}\right.$$

Comment: Welcoe to Maths SX! Can α and β take  independent values?

Comment: Here's two ways you should improve your question. First, use MathJax in your question; it is much easier to read $\sqrt{2}$  than squareroot(2) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Second, explain what you've tried, show where you failed, and generally ask a more detailed and explicit question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960.

Comment: This is a necessary condition, but it is not a sufficient one. The number of solutions also depend on the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810570/265466.

Comment: X-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/302320/91764